# How can i show accurate route map in react-native-maps with google apis

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

to draw the route map between different points in react-native-maps.it works fine, I used polyline to display route, the route map is displayed but it gives straight lines instead of a detailed route map as shown in the image.

[image]

how can draw the accurate route map using googleapis or any other module?

Also tried react-native-maps-directions but if I want to get route map for more than 10 waypoints my app crashes
you can refer this link https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions/issues/110